# PostGIS query to retrieve geometry that intersects both a bbox intersects and also matches other columns

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, spatial-index

I am relatively new to GIS, so have been searching around to try find a similar case to the one I am facing but have come up short.

Specifically I want to store multiple sets of geometry features in PostgreSQL (the polygon features from separate geojson files) and be able to query them using a bbox. I would also like these files to have different resolutions that can be queried.

**Update (9/5/2020)**
I have added my specific code as below to enable more context:

setup.sql

```
-- Extensions
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

-- Schema
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS geojson_testing;

-- Table & Columns
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geojson_testing.layermapgeometry();
ALTER TABLE geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS tinyid TEXT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS zoom BIGINT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS geometrybbox GEOMETRY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS geometry GEOMETRY NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS geojsonfeature JSONB NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS properties JSONB NOT NULL;

-- Indexes
CREATE INDEX geojson_testing_tinyid_idx 
    ON geojson_testing.layermapgeometry USING GIST(tinyid, zoom, geometrybbox);


-- Insert GeoJson features as geometry
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geojson_testing.insertGeoJson(opts JSONB) 
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
DECLARE
    _tinyid         TEXT    := opts->>'tinyid';
    _zoom           BIGINT  := COALESCE(opts->>'zoom', '-1')::BIGINT;
    _geojson        JSONB   := opts->'geojson';
BEGIN
    -- Remove any previous geometry
    DELETE FROM geojson_testing.layermapgeometry WHERE tinyid = _tinyid AND zoom = _zoom;

    -- Add new geometry rows based on 'features'
    INSERT INTO 
        geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
        (
            tinyid, 
            zoom, 
            properties, 
            geojsonfeature,
            geometry,
            geometrybbox
        )
    SELECT 
        _tinyid as tinyid, 
        _zoom as zoom,
        props.properties as properties,
        props.geometry as geojsonfeature,
        ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(props.geometry) as geometry,
        ST_Envelope(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(props.geometry)) as geometrybbox
    FROM 
        jsonb_to_recordset(_geojson->'features') AS props(properties jsonb, geometry jsonb);

    RETURN jsonb_build_object('success', TRUE);
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

-- Retrieve GeoJson based on BBOX
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geojson_testing.fetchGeoJson(opts JSONB) 
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
DECLARE
    _tinyid         TEXT    := opts->>'tinyid';
    _zoom           BIGINT  := COALESCE(opts->>'zoom', '-1')::BIGINT;
    _xmin           FLOAT   := (opts->'bbox'->>'xmin')::FLOAT;
    _ymin           FLOAT   := (opts->'bbox'->>'ymin')::FLOAT;
    _xmax           FLOAT   := (opts->'bbox'->>'xmax')::FLOAT;
    _ymax           FLOAT   := (opts->'bbox'->>'ymax')::FLOAT;
    _result         JSONB;
BEGIN

    SELECT jsonb_build_object(
        'type',     'FeatureCollection',
        'features', jsonb_agg(features.feat)
    )
    INTO _result
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            jsonb_build_object(
                'type', 'Feature', 
                'geometry', geojsonfeature, 
                'properties', properties
            ) AS feat
            FROM geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
            WHERE 
                tinyid = _tinyid AND 
                zoom = _zoom AND
                geometrybbox && ST_MakeEnvelope(_xmin, _ymin, _xmax, _ymax)
    ) AS features;

    RETURN jsonb_build_object('success', TRUE, 'result', _result);
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

populate.sql

```
SELECT geojson_testing.insertGeoJson($$
{
    "tinyid":"abcd1",
    "zoom": 1,
    "geojson": {/*Large 40mb geojson wiht many polygon features*/}
}
$$::jsonb)
```

My end goal is to optimize `geojson_testing.fetchGeoJson` to be as fast as possible.

While testing I have been playing with the raw SQL select call:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT 
    count(*)
    FROM geojson_testing.layermapgeometry 
    WHERE 
        tinyid = 'abcd1' AND
        zoom = 1 AND
        geometry && ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
```

This is coming back at roughly 100ms in pgadmin each time, but what I find especially strange is that when I query the geometrybbox column instead of the geometry column it still returns in roughly the same time. I think it is not using my index, but even if it wasn't I would have expected geometrybbox to run much faster because it is querying simple bboxs instead of a complex polygons.

I am not very familiar with explain results, but this is what it looks like when querying using geometry:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=1597.38..1597.39 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5.369..5.369 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on layermapgeometry  (cost=0.00..1597.12 rows=105 width=0) (actual time=0.248..5.337 rows=298 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((tinyid = 'abcd1'::text) AND (zoom = 1) AND (geometry && '010300000001000000050000007B14AEF7EF4861403C8BBD70FC8141C07B14AEF7EF486140F9C2B362446941C07B14AEB7EE5C6140F9C2B362446941C07B14AEB7EE5C61403C8BBD70FC8141C07B14AEF7EF4861403C8BBD70FC8141C0'::geometry))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 1593"
"Planning Time: 0.160 ms"
"Execution Time: 5.392 ms"
```

and for geometrybbox:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=349.33..349.34 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.698..0.699 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on layermapgeometry  (cost=9.22..349.07 rows=105 width=0) (actual time=0.356..0.671 rows=298 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((tinyid = 'abcd1'::text) AND (geometrybbox && '010300000001000000050000007B14AEF7EF4861403C8BBD70FC8141C07B14AEF7EF486140F9C2B362446941C07B14AEB7EE5C6140F9C2B362446941C07B14AEB7EE5C61403C8BBD70FC8141C07B14AEF7EF4861403C8BBD70FC8141C0'::geometry))"
"        Filter: (zoom = 1)"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=118"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on geojson_testing_tinyid_idx  (cost=0.00..9.20 rows=105 width=0) (actual time=0.325..0.325 rows=298 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((tinyid = 'abcd1'::text) AND (geometrybbox && '010300000001000000050000007B14AEF7EF4861403C8BBD70FC8141C07B14AEF7EF486140F9C2B362446941C07B14AEB7EE5C6140F9C2B362446941C07B14AEB7EE5C61403C8BBD70FC8141C07B14AEF7EF4861403C8BBD70FC8141C0'::geometry))"
"Planning Time: 0.269 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.774 ms"
```

Any further help would be great.

Comment: what about multiple geometry columns with varying resolutions that are queried depending on scale? and above I think you use the word 'dataset' when you mean 'feature'...

Comment: I hadn't considered that, that could work well with either of the directions I started above. I was hoping to seriously reduce the 1.5s it took before I even started considering resolution, do you think it is reasonable for me to hope to get it to like 200ms or am I being too hopeful?

Comment: can you add the EXPLAIN ANALYSE output to your question, and some clues as to size of table, geometries and bounding box - i.e. does your query return most of the table or one or two rows?

Comment: In fact looking at your query some more shouldn't ID=_ID match just one feature making the rest of the query pretty much irrelevant

Comment: Depending on the level of simplification of the geometry and the scale of the query, I would imagine so. Definitely worth exploring I think.

Comment: @DPSSpatial I have updated the question with a lot more information which will helpfully make it easier to make sense of. Apologies for any confusion I added, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I have read up a bit more, and although not entirely clear to me, I presume the timings pgadmin is giving me of 100ms are actually inaccurate, and I should be looking more closely at the "Execution Time" etc from the explain analyse above. Which means its actually only taking roughly 6ms in the manual geometry query and about 1ms when querying the geometrybbox column (and I think it is also using the correct index). So maybe I can stick to what I am doing, and all is actually running at a reasonable speed.